# how to find data from database by matching single word in a string stored in table's column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, search, sql-like

Here is the query to find the address from a table where it matches to variable `$fromCity`,

```
$fromCity= "324 West Gore Street, Orlando, FL 32806, USA";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vendor_info WHERE mailing_address LIKE '$fromCity'";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$company = $stmt->fetchAll();
dd($company);
```

In the table `vendor_info` the column `mailing address` is like
`324 WEST GORE STREETORLANDO, FL 32806`

I want to get result if any single word is match from `mailing_address` column

now the result of `dd(company);` is empty array,

kindly help me out to figure out this solution, it is in symfony,

Comment: try `'%$fromCity%'` in where

Comment: You could explode the City string into an array of single words. Then use it to query all the words. (either using different combinations of `like` and `or`) But be careful, your current string contains `USA` so you would get all companies in the US. -  And before you explode the original string, maybe replace the commas.

Comment: Use not LIKE but INSTR/LOCATE.

Comment: You are using prepared statements incorrectly. Values don't go in the query, bind them.

Comment: Are you sure about `if any single word is match`? The `street` term I would assume would match a majority of records.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
   $fromCity = "324 West Gore Street, Orlando, FL 32806";
   $fromCity_arr = explode(', ', $fromCity);
   $whereStr = '';
   foreach($fromCity_arr as $fromCity_el){
     if(!empty($whereStr)){$whereStr .= " AND ";}
     $whereStr .= "mailing_address LIKE '%".$fromCity_el."%'";
   }
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM vendor_info WHERE $whereStr";
   ......
```

Result:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
  vendor_info 
WHERE 
  mailing_address LIKE '%324 West Gore Street%' 
 AND 
  mailing_address LIKE '%Orlando%' 
 AND 
  mailing_address LIKE '%FL 32806%'
```

Comment: `$fromCity = "%';--"`

Answer (score 0):

@mscdeveloper's answer is basicly correct - but as you use doctrine you should also use prepared statements to be safe(r) from sql injections.

```
$fromCity = "324 West Gore Street, Orlando, FL 32806";
$fromCity_arr = explode(', ', $fromCity);
$stm = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(MyModel::class)->getQueryBuilder('a');
for($i=0;$i<count($fromCity_arr);$i++) {
    $stm->andWhere('a.mailing_address like ?)
        ->setParameter($i+1, '%'.$fromCity_arr[$i].'%'); 
}

$result = $stm->getQuery()->getResult();
dump($stm->getQuery()->getSql());
dd($result);
```